# Is there a maximum return length for a character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a dynamic character "string pointer"/array and my code will not print values is the characters typed in exceed 249 characters. I am just wondering if there is a maximum return length for a character array/"string pointer".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *input() {
    char *inpt; 
    char check;
    int i;
    int count;

    i = 0;
    count = 1;
    check = '\0';

    inpt = (char*)malloc(1);

    while (check != '\n') {
        check = getchar(); 
        if (check == '\n') {
            break;
        } else {
            inpt[i] = check;
            i++;
            count++;
            inpt = realloc(inpt, count);
        }
    }
    inpt[i] = '\0';

    char *retrn;
    retrn = inpt;

    free(inpt);

    printf("%d \n", i);

    return retrn;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *name;
    printf("Please print name: \n");
    name = input();
    printf("%s is the name \n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You’re returning a freed pointer; `retrn` doesn’t really change anything here compared to `free(inpt); return input;`. You can return it without freeing it if you make the caller free it instead.

Comment: You are only limited to the amount of memory that your OS will allocate to your program and the physical memory in your computer. (and the limit of addressing that can be done with a 32 or 64-bit pointers). Your allocation scheme (`realloc` for every char) is horribly inefficient. Just start with say, `size_t mem=32;` and then keep a count of the chars added, then when reached `void *tmp = realloc (input, mem * 2); if (!tmp) {/* handle error */}; input = tmp; mem *= 2;` and keep going.

Comment: Your title points in an entirely wrong direction, still there's an answer to that question as well: The maximum length is the max value of a `size_t`. On most platforms, this equals the whole size of the available address space. So it's *huge* and you'll (almost) never run into a problem with this.

Comment: @FelixPalmen sorry I'm new to the whole stack over flow thing

Comment: @Zbit56 that wasn't criticism, just pointing out that although your assumption about the source of the problem was wrong, there's still an answer to the question you gave in your title.

Comment: @FelixPalmen well thank you for answering the question I was also curious about that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, there are a number of schemes to allocate memory dynamically. One thing you want to avoid from an efficiency standpoint is needlessly reallocating for every character. Rather than call `realloc` for every character added to name, allocate a reasonable number of characters to hold name, and if you reach that amount, then reallocate, doubling the current allocation size, update your variable holding the current size and keep going.

You already have an array index, so there is no need to keep a separate `count`. Just use your array index as the counter, insuring your have at least `index + 1` characters available to provide space to *nul-terminate* `inpt`.

There is no need to keep separate pointers in `input()`. Just allocate for `inpt` and return `inpt` as the pointer to your block of memory when done. (don't forget to `free (name);` in `main()` which will free the memory you allocated in `input`.

Never `realloc` the pointer directly. (e.g. DON'T `inpt = realloc (inpt, size);`) If `realloc` fails it returns `NULL` causing the loss of a pointer to to the allocated block `inpt` referenced prior to the `realloc` call. Instead use a temporary pointer, validate that `realloc` succeeded, and then assign the new block to `inpt` (example below)

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MEMSZ 32  /* initial allocation size (must be at least 1) */

char *input (void)
{
    char *inpt = NULL, check;
    size_t mem = MEMSZ, ndx = 0;

    if (!(inpt = malloc (mem))) {   /* allocate/validate  mem chars */
        fprintf (stderr, "input() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* you must check for EOF in addition to '\n' */
    while ((check = getchar()) && check != '\n' && check != EOF) 
    {   /* check index + 1 to insure space to nul-terminate */
        if (ndx + 1 == mem) {       /* if mem limit reached realloc */
            void *tmp = realloc (inpt, mem * 2);    /* use tmp ptr */
            if (!tmp) {             /* validate reallocation */
                fprintf (stderr, "realloc(): memory exhausted.\n");
                break;      /* on failure, preserve existing chars */
            }
            inpt = tmp;     /* assign new block of memory to inpt */
            mem *= 2;       /* set mem to new allocaiton size */
        }
        inpt[ndx++] = check;    /* assign, increment index */
    }
    inpt[ndx] = 0;          /* nul-terminate */

    return inpt;            /* return pointer to allocated block */
}

int main (void)
{
    char *name = NULL;

    printf ("Please enter name: ");
    if (!(name = input()))  /* validate input() succeeded */
        return 1;

    printf ("You entered      : %s\n", name);
    free (name);    /* don't forget to free name */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/entername
Please enter name: George Charles Butte
You entered      : George Charles Butte
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/entername
==2566== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2566== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2566== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2566== Command: ./bin/entername
==2566==
Please enter name: George Charles Butte
You entered      : George Charles Butte
==2566==
==2566== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2566==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2566==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==2566==
==2566== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2566==
==2566== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2566== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you that was very help full. Im just beginning to learn C only been programming in C for about a month and a 1/2 now. So all help is appreciated.

Comment: C is a fantasic language, but there is a lot to learn. Don't try and learn it all in a month (or a year for that matter) -- enjoy the ride. No language gives you as much control over the hardware as C (aside from assembly). C gives you the control, AND puts the total responsibility on  you to make sure you are doing it correctly. When dealing with memory, arrays, whatever, you have to put your accountant hat on and make sure you account for the memory you use. C won't prevent you from writing outside of your block, it relies on you to validate your memory use. Good luck with your coding `:)`

Comment: @chux - you sure about that? take the case of `1-byte` allocated initially and then read a line of one char -- you reallocate to always insure space for termination -- or maybe I'm just getting senile.... (the check to insure adequate space is done first in the loop on this incarnation to allow reading `mem-1` chars before `realloc` rather than `realloc` at `mem-2`)

Comment: I've switched back and forth between `realloc` before assignment and check and `realloc` after at times. This time I wanted to make sure you could start with an initial allocation of 1-byte as originally done in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with the length of the string you attempt to return, but that you return a pointer to memory that no longer is allocated to you:

```
char *retrn;
retrn = inpt;

free(inpt);

return retrn;
```

When you do `retrn = inpt` you don't copy the memory, instead you have two pointers pointing to the same memory. Then you `free` that memory and return a pointer to the newly free'd memory. That pointer can't of course not be dereferenced and any attempt of doing that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution is not any temporary variable like `retrn`, but to simply not `free` the memory in the `input` function. Instead return `inpt` and in the calling function (`main` in your case) you `free` the memory.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely due to using free memory. Your assignment input to retrn is not creating another copy. You'll get undefined behaviour, perhaps including what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

There are intrinsic limits for the size of an array:

- available memory is limited: `malloc()` and `realloc()` may return `NULL` if the request cannot be honored due to lack of core memory. You should definitely check for `malloc()` and `realloc()` success.
- system quotas may limit the amount of memory available to your process to a lower number than actual physical memory installed or virtual memory accessible in the system.
- the maximum size for an array is the maximum value for the type `size_t`: `SIZE_MAX` which has a minimum value of `65535`, but you use type `int` for your requests to `malloc()` or `realloc()`, that may have a smaller range than `size_t`. Type `int` is 32 bits on most current desktop systems where `size_t` may be 64 bits and available memory may be much more than 2GB. Use `size_t` instead of `int`.

Note however that your problem comes from a much simpler bug: you free the memory block you allocated for the string and return a copy of the pointer, which now points to freed memory. Accessing this memory has undefined behavior, which can be anything, including apparent correct behavior upto 249 bytes and failure beyond.

Note also that you should use type `int` for `check` and compare the return value of `getchar()` to EOF to avoid an endless loop if the input does not contain a newline (such as en empty file).

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *input(void) {
    char *p = malloc(1);  /* simplistic reallocation, 1 byte at a time */
    size_t i = 0;         /* use size_t for very large input */
    int c;                /* use int to detect EOF reliably */

    if (p == NULL) {
        return NULL;  /* allocation error */
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        char *newp = realloc(p, i + 2);
        if (newp == NULL) {
            free(p);   /* avoid a memory leak */
            return NULL;  /* reallocation error */
        }
        p = newp;
        p[i++] = c;
    }
    if (i == 0 && c == EOF) {
        free(p);
        return NULL;  /* end of file */
    }
    p[i] = '\0';
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *name;
    printf("Please print name: ");
    name = input();
    if (name == NULL) {
        printf("input() returned NULL\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s is the name\n", name);
        free(name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a maximum return length for a character array in C

The maximum size of a character array is `SIZE_MAX`.  `SIZE_MAX` is at least 65535.

> I am just wondering if there is a maximum return length for a character array/"string pointer".

For a *string*, its maximum *size* is `SIZE_MAX` and the maximum *length* is `SIZE_MAX - 1`.